# Java / Libgdx LwjglApplicationConfiguration backgroundFPS doesn't work

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm working on a multiplayer game, because of that it should also be rendered and calculated when the window is not in focus. I searched a little bit and found a way for libgdx to render in background, normally it should work by setting backgroundFPS = 0; like here :

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.title = "32 Bit Game v : 0.4.75";

cfg.vSyncEnabled = false;
cfg.forceExit = true;

cfg.backgroundFPS = 0;
cfg.foregroundFPS = 0;

cfg.width = 1920;
cfg.height = 1080;

cfg.fullscreen = false;

cfg.addIcon("Icon/Logo.png", FileType.Internal);

//System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true");

new LwjglApplication(new MenuCreate(), cfg);
```

Like I did in my code, but it doesn't work, every time my game loses focus it still doesn't render. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplicationConfiguration.html#backgroundFPS) you should rather use the `-1` value

> Target framerate when the window is not in the foreground. The CPU sleeps as needed. Use 0 to never sleep, -1 to not render.

So it should be:

```
    cfg.backgroundFPS = -1;
```

Comment: You read his issue wrong. He actually WANTS to render in the background.